# Getting x and y position of mouse pointer relative to an element

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Hi can anyone help with this?
When I move the mouse pointer of a  element,  I would like to retrieve the x and y positions relative to the `<div>`

E.g - when I put the mouse pointer at the top left point of the div I would expect to get an X of 1 and a Y of 1.

This needs to be compatible for Internet Explorer

Thanks all for your time.

This works, trouble was I was calling it from the onclick event which didnt give the scrollLeft and scrollTop values.  I should be able to get the position from this by using the calculations of the Divs top and left values.

```
function getMouseXY(ctrl)        
{
    var tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    var tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;

    document.getElementById('<%=txtXPos.ClientID%>').value = tempX;
    document.getElementById('<%=txtXPos.ClientID%>').value = tempY;
}
```

Thanks to all except LincolnK ! ! lol

Comment: is jquery a option for you, or do you need a pure JS solution that does not inculde a framework?

Comment: thanks lincoln for those kind words.

Comment: examples ive seen tend to use the following to get the mouse position coordinates var tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft; var tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;

Comment: that would work for getting the mouse coordinates but when I scroll the scrollTop value and scrollLeft value are always 0

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
function myOnMouseMove(element) {
  var e = window.event
  var relativeX = e.screenX - element.scrollLeft;
  var relativeY = e.screenY - element.scrollTop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me:

```
function getOffset( el ) 
{
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) 
    {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
var x = getOffset( document.getElementById('MY DIV ID') ).left;
var Y = getOffset( document.getElementById('MY DIV ID') ).top;

function myOnYourEvent()
{
    var relativeX = window.event.clientX;
    var relativeY = window.event.clientY;
    var my_div_x = relativeX - x;
    var my_div_y = relativeY - Y;
    alert(my_div_x  + " " + my_div_y);
}
```